# How to look up a value inside a list in a predicate, in PROLOG

Tags: list, search, prolog, predicate

So far I've done my fair amount of research and I've tried different methods, however even after reading multiple stack overflow answers and even a PDF from Addison Wesley, I can't find the way to do it. Here is the code

```
use_module(library(func)).
% importing library "func"

scale([c, d, e, f, g, a, b]).
scale(c, major, [c, d, e, f, g, a, b]).
scale(c, minor, [c, d, e_b, f, g, a_b, b_b]).

%1st attempt 
search(note, scale):- scale(note, scale).

%2nd attempt
scaleOf(note, type_scale):- scale(note, type_scale).

on(item,[item|rest]).  

on(item,[disregardHead|tail]):-
    scale(tail),
    on(item, tail).

%3rd attempt 

fatherOf(father,type, son):- scale(father, type, sons), search(son, type, sons).
search(son, type, []):- !, fail.
search(son, type, [son|l]):- !, true.
search(son, type, [c|l]):- search(son, type, l).
```

What am I attempting? Simple, something that can iterate through the predicate scale(c, [c, d, e, f, g, a, b]). But I can't get it right.

Edit: I have multiple predicates because someone else suggested creating a predicate that would differentiate one scale from the other. I thought I could cram it inside any algorithm but I guess PROLOG is not that lenient :p

Comment: You here have two predicates `scale`, one `scale/1` with a list of notes, and one `scale/3` with a list of scales for `c`? Can you explain *what* you aim to do, and how these predicates provide the info?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry, I should've specified. I thought I could make these work with the other implementations, but I couldn't. If I could, I would love to have an algorithm that can look through this list. I'm still very new with PROLOG sorry.

Comment: but is it possible to explain *what* you aim to do? What predicate do you aim to implement? What queries should succeed, what queries should fail?

Comment: I'm sorry for being so unclear, I just want to look up X note inside a list of predicates. Have, for example, the same list but as scale(d, minor, [c, d, e, f, g, a, b_b]). If this predicate is true then the program will return true. The "user" should just input scale(d, minor) for it to start looking through the knowledge base. (Which should contain all mayor and minor scales. I've yet to come up with something better). I tried to return all the elements inside said list _inside_ the predicate scale(d, minor, [c, ...]) but thats a headache for another day since prolog doesn't work like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [**`member/2`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=member/2). This can be used to search, unify with a member, or generate a list.

So you can search with:

```
search(Note, Scale, Item) :-
    scale(Note, Scale, Items),
    member(Item, Items).
```

It is important that `Note`, `Scale`, `Item` and `Items` start with an **U**ppercase, since identifiers with a lower case are constants or functors. Identifiers with an uppercase are *variables*.

This will thus unify `Item` with the items in the list, for the given sample data we for example obtain:

```
?- search(c, minor, Item).
Item = c ;
Item = d ;
Item = e_b ;
Item = f ;
Item = g ;
Item = a_b ;
Item = b_b.
```